# $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{C}-\left\{0\right\},$ $\text{Im}f<-1$ for $|z| = 1/2,2$; show $f(1)\neq 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Suppose $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}-\left\{0\right\}$ and that $ \Im(f) < -1$ for $|z|=1/2$ and $|z| = 2$. Show $f(1)\neq 0.$

I have tried Cauchy's Integral formula, but it seemed to be a dead end. Any and all hints are appreciated.

Comment: Is this a right way? : Let $D = \{z : 1/2 < |z| < 2\}$ and consider a holomorphic function $g(z) = \exp(f(z) /i)$ on $D$, and use a maximum modulus theorem...

Comment: Thanks! With your $g$, we have $|g|<1/e<1$ on $\partial D$, so $f(1) = 0$ would violate the Maximum Modulus Principle.